# PyQt5 Shortcuts in Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been trying to figure out how to get PyQt5 shortcuts to work on OSX. I can't find any information on the PyQt5 docs and the [Qt5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html) say:

> On Mac, shortcuts are disabled by default. Call qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic() to enable them. However, because mnemonic shortcuts do not fit in with Aqua's guidelines, Qt will not show the shortcut character underlined.

I then found out on the  [Global Qt Declarations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exportedfunctions.html#void-qt-set-sequence-auto-mnemonic-bool-enable) that we need to declare the function before calling it. However I'm not too sure how to do this in Python. I've tried:

> def qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic(enable): pass
>   def qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic(bool): pass

Neither have worked and after extensive Googling, I'm at a loss of how to do this. If anyone has any idea on how to enable the keyboard shortcuts I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: `from PyQt5.QtGui import qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic`

Comment: I received an ImportError: cannot import name 'qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic'

Comment: That's because it's only available on osx.

Comment: And I am using OSX on a macbook pro to run this.

Comment: I can't actually test it myself, but it was definitely added in pyqt-4.2, and I don't see any evidence that it was ever removed. Open up a python interpreter, do `from PyQt4 import Qt` and then use tab completion on `Qt.qt_`. What do you see?

Comment: I don't have PyQt4, but with PyQt5 tab completion doesn't bring anything up.

Comment: I had a look at the sources, and it's still there in the latest pyqt4 (in sip/QtGui/qapplication.sip) - but it's now missing in pyqt5. At present, though, I can't find any information on why it wasn't included in pyqt5.

Comment: It's back in PyQt5 5.15.10